# full-text search 7608 (0x80004005) error message debug

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-2000

Someone tries to run the following line :

```
exec sp_fulltext_column 'tbElementFullTextMvCustomProperty5', 'EMVCP_E_NAME', 'add', 0, NULL
```

and then receives the following error :

```
(1 row(s) affected)


(1 row(s) affected)

Server: Msg 7608, Level 17, State 1, Procedure sp_fulltext_column, Line 138
An unknown full-text failure (80040d23) occurred in function EnumCatalogs on full-text catalog 'catElementFullTextMvCustomProperty5'.
```

I have searched online and thought that maybe the full-text search is not enabled on this database.
According to the part "[How to set up full-text search on a database](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/295772)" of this note, it would seem that you can run the following procedures to enable full text search :

```
USE <DB_NAME>
GO
EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable'
GO
EXEC sp_fulltext_catalog 'FTC_titles', 'create'
GO
EXEC sp_fulltext_table titles, 'create', 'FTC_titles', UPKCL_titleidind
GO
EXEC sp_fulltext_column titles, title, 'add'
GO
EXEC sp_fulltext_table titles, 'activate'
GO
EXEC sp_fulltext_catalog 'FTC_titles', 'start_full'
GO
```

This query ran for 20 minutes so I cancelled it, I guessed it did not work. Did I do wrong ? Should I had kept it going ? What should be my next debugging step ?

This is a windows server 2003 running a sqlserver 2000 database

Thanks